# For the language $\{w \mid w \in \Sigma^*, w \neq \lambda\}$, is the following regular expression correct?

Tags: regular-language, regular-expressions

For the language $\{w \mid w \in \Sigma^*, w \neq \lambda\}$, is the following regular expression correct?

$(a+b)^+$  . Which is $(a+b)$ to the power of $+$ which I think accepts all combinations of $a$ and $b$ except for the empty string.

Can someone please confirm?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I've fixed the question except I don't know what the format is for the not equal to symbol.  So, you can read that as w is not equal to the empty string.

Comment: You are correct.

Answer (score 1):

yes it is correct (assuming that Σ={a,b} )

Answer (score 0):

Some people don't allow $r^+$ in their definition of regular expressions, in which case you'd have to settle for using $(\mathtt{a}+\mathtt{b})(\mathtt{a}+\mathtt{b})^*$, but otherwise, I'd agree with May: you got it.